# Windows 8.1 IPSec by GPO - no firewall rules generated

Tags: windows, firewall, group-policy, ipsec

I am seeing very strange behavior on Windows 8.1 clients when attempting to configure IPSec rules via group policy. I am configuring several rules through several policies, to be able to target the individual rules. One particular policy does not result in any firewall rules being generated on Windows 8.1 clients, though RSoP tells me the policy is, in fact, being applied. On a Windows 2012 R2 server, the firewall rule is created as expected. I cannot find any documentation on whether the Windows firewall is limited with respect to connection security rules on Windows 8.1, nor what is causing this behavior. Any advice as to what to look for would be appreciated.

Comment: What does gpresult /h show?

Comment: As I said, gpresult /h shows all policies I expect to be applied being applied. One of them is not generating a firewall rule, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fact I only saw this on Windows 8.1 clients was a red herring. When copying GPOs containing firewall rules, The Group Policy Management Console will create a new GUID for the new GPO - but copy the firewall rule object verbatim, including GUID. Explicitly making a copy of the subobject (i.e., firewall rule) resolved the problem.